# What is Partial Crossbar Interconnection

Tags: fpga, routing

I have difficulties understanding the concept of *Partial Crossbar Interconnection* and I could not find any reference on internet to read on. I have the photo below from a lecture slide of many years ago and I can not recall what was it about. I remember another alternative was *nearest neighbor interconnection* but that itself had many problems when it comes to implementation.

So my question is what is *Partial Crossbar Interconnection* and what can be understood out of the image below?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I interpret your diagram you can connect each group of 4 input/outputs to the I/O pin group [1..4] of your choice. That is a crossbar. But in FPGA1 you can't choose to which I/O pin within the group your A connects: the connections within the group are fixed A->1a B->1b C->1c, D->1d.

In FGGA2 you can (probably) switch the lines within a group, but you can't switch between groups.

The total effect is that you can

- in the first level crossbar direct a group of 4 in/ouputs to a group of I/O pins
- in the second-level crossbar direct a pin within a group to aqnother pin within that group